# Does $f'(x)\in \mathbb Z$ a.e. implies that $f$ is an affine function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, derivatives

Conjecture: Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be an **everywhere** differentiable function and  assume that $f'(x) \in \mathbb Z$ **almost everywhere**. Then is $f$ necessarily an affine function?

Can you give me a proof or a counter-example ? I thought of the devil's staircase, but this is not differentiable everywhere.

Comment: Use Darboux's theorem for the derivative.
https://teachingcalculus.com/2014/08/18/darbouxs-theorem/
to deduce that the derivative is constant.

Comment: Do you assume that $f $ is **everywhere** or **almost everywhere** differentiable?

Comment: @uniquesolution But the derivative is only assumed to be integral a.e., so the application of Darboux, if it works at all, isn't all that straightforward. Or did I miss something?

Comment: The application of Darboux is very simple. Suppose $f'(a)=z_1$ and $f'(b)=z_2$.  Then, between a and b, $f'$ has to take every value between $z_1$ and $z_2$, both integer and non-integer.  If it can't be an integer, then $z_1=z_2$ and the derivative everywhere is that constant value.

Comment: @Paul Why can't $f'$ attain all noninteger values in $[z_1,z_2]$ on a set of measure zero?

Comment: I found this which can answer my question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266377/how-quickly-can-the-derivative-of-an-everywhere-differentiable-function-change-s

Comment: Perhaps I shall return to this question$\,\ldots\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $f'$ must be constant. This has been answered in the comments; the result in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266377/how-quickly-can-the-derivative-of-an-everywhere-differentiable-function-change-s gives a kind of positive measure Darboux theorem. This is a special case of [How irregular can $f'$ be beyond Darboux's Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570732/how-irregular-can-f-be-beyond-darbouxs-theorem/2572866#2572866)